# AWS API Gateway HTTP Proxy - Original Request URI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, http-proxy

we have a signing algorithm that uses the request URI.

So the client signs before making the request, so the clients perspective of the request uri is the AWS API gateway endpoint.

Obviously running this through a api http proxy,  which passes through the signed request, but changes the request_uri causes some issues with verification on the ultimate end point.

Is there a simple way to pass through the original request uri, in any form?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any simple way to pass/get the original request URI.  There is enough info in the context object that you should be able to re-assemble it.  See [context variable documentation here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference)